# How can I combine both line graph and bar graph in achartengine?

Tags: android, achartengine

I'm developing an Android app that suppose to have graphs. How can I combine both line graph and bar graph using "achartengine".

Answer (score 0):

You will have to build an XYCombinedChart. Please see an example [here](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/source/browse/trunk/achartengine/demo/org/achartengine/chartdemo/demo/chart/CombinedTemperatureChart.java).